# hs_err_pid2118.log: This file appeared in my home directory : A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, files, home-directory

I have 2 unknown file(which i know nothing about them) in my home directory.
I remember i had too many of them in /home directory before i reinstalled ubuntu(to upgrade to 18.04).
Yesterday i had one of them and today i have 2 which named:

 `hs_err_pid2498.log` and `hs_err_pid2118.log`.

First lines of hs_err_pid2118.log(982 lines):

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe65506977a, pid=2118, tid=0x00007fe5fbfff700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_141-b15) (build 1.8.0_141-BLFS-b15)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.141-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~BufferBlob::jni_fast_GetLongField
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fe600133000):  JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2207, stack(0x00007fe5fbeff000,0x00007fe5fc000000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007fe66d28ef60, RBX=0x00007fe6001331e0, RCX=0x0000000000000001, RDX=0x0000000000000042
RSP=0x00007fe5fbffe7d8, RBP=0x00007fe5fbffe800, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x00007fe6001331e0
R8 =0x00000000000001f4, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x00000000000001ba, R11=0x00007fe66ccdcbc0
R12=0x00007fe5e80550e0, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007fe63cca4ae0, R15=0x00007fe600133000
RIP=0x00007fe65506977a, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fe5fbffe7d8)
.
.
.

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fe65506977a)
.
.
.
```

First lines of hs_err_pid2498.log(974 lines):

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd2a4e6077a, pid=2498, tid=0x00007fd27c2ba700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_141-b15) (build 1.8.0_141-BLFS-b15)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.141-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~BufferBlob::jni_fast_GetLongField
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fd2540f3000):  JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2578, stack(0x00007fd27c1ba000,0x00007fd27c2bb000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007fd2ba326f60, RBX=0x00007fd2540f31e0, RCX=0x0000000000000001, RDX=0x0000000000000042
RSP=0x00007fd27c2b97f8, RBP=0x00007fd27c2b9820, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x00007fd2540f31e0
R8 =0x00000000c0066698, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000324, R11=0x00007fd2a4f09558
R12=0x00007fd21c0373e0, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007fd27ddd3ae0, R15=0x00007fd2540f3000
RIP=0x00007fd2a4e6077a, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fd27c2b97f8)
.
.
.
```

What are these files?

Can i delete them?(what will happen?)

I didn't have files like them until 2 or 3 months ago!

I think when i use `tor` service(searching or downloading) these files appears,cause i didn't download things using tor before(until 2 or 3 months ago).

If it was about installing software,Note that: i almost didn't install anything in 4 days ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are log files. They are generated after the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) crashes. Usually they can be deleted without a worry, as they are just log files.

They have details on your system explaining what happened and what your system looked like at the time it crashed. Unless you developed the Java application, they won't really be very useful for you.

Comment: Can we stop creating in future scenarios?

Comment: Apparently, you can set a JVM option, as seen in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800098
However, the JVM should not be crashing frequently, and, if it does crash, the log files usually can help a lot with finding the error cause.